# How to pass variable inside index in Javascript push

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach

How to pass variable inside index in JavaScript push.I am using angular.
This is what I did so far:

```
angular.forEach(Val, function (Value,Key) {
    angular.forEach(Value, function (Value1,Key1) {
        saveDetailArr.push({ 'option_id':Val['option_id'],Key1:$scope[Key1] });
    });
});
```

Key1 contains "header,footer,text1,text2,left_contianer etc".
Basically,I want the value of Key1 instead of string "Key1"
Currently,it look like: `{'option_id':21,Key1:'abc'}`
But I want it like this:`{'option_id':21,header:'abc'}`
How can I achieve this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bracket notation for variable property names. In your case `obj[Key1]` should work:

```
angular.forEach(Val, function (Value,Key) {
    angular.forEach(Value, function (Value1,Key1) {
        var obj = { 'option_id':Val['option_id'] };
        obj[Key1] = $scope[Key1];
        saveDetailArr.push(obj);
    });
});
```

Comment: If I have to make the object like this in same example.
object{
  option_id=21,
  value=
   {
    object{header="abc",'footer'="xyz"}
   }
  }
How can i achieve this?

Comment: Basically I want to wrap all the record of same options_id.